# Parse xml file in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xml-parsing

I have an xml file which looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Response val="true">
    <Version vers="1.2"/>
    <Release>
         This release allows start
    </Release>
</Response>
```

In my cocoa application, I want to parse informations after "=" and between "release flags".

How can I do this?

Comment: The phrase "release flags" doesn't appear anywhere in your XML.

Comment: "This release allows start" between the 2 release flags :)

Comment: You mean the content of the Release element?

Comment: yes and also the values after "=" for the response and version elements

Answer (score 0):

This is a great review of Objective-C XML parsers:

[How To Choose the Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

For a similarly simple task, I considered NSXMLParser before settling on TouchXML.